# What are the dangers of unsafe user-inputted text in Django?

Tags: javascript, django, security, xss

One of my coworkers recently introduced a vulnerability to an in-development page. This allows the user to insert 30 chars of unescaped code that will be executed with the `|safe` filter. So html unsafe chars (`<`, `>`, `'`, `"` or `&`) can be freely inserted into the page template.

The vulnerability exists in a error message on a form, so it does not allow a hacker to edit what is shown to other users, only himself. I wish to show my co-worker the danger of the vulnerability with a horrific example. Also, I'm personally intrigued on a professional level on what the absolute worst case with such a vulnerability like this would be. I know in PHP (possibly older versions) this would allow the user to echo out the contents of server files. Will this vulnerability allow me to similarly show content in the settings file? The Django Devs (bless them) have wisely chosen that `{` will not be escaped even with the `|safe` filter. So it cannot be used to show context variables.

The worst I've been able to come up with on my own is insertion (and execution) of any JS file located anywhere on the web, which would be horrific if it could affect other users, but it doesn't seem that bad if the js file will only be executed for the hacker himself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the error message can be triggered through GET parameters, then you can simply craft a link that executes the JS when the victim clicks it.

ie: `http://example.com?email=<script>alert(1)</script>`

Otherwise, the only other way (that I can think of) to exploit this would be to use a form on another page (assuming this request is allowed).

```
<form name="xssForm" action="http://example.com" method="POST">
    <input type="hidden" name="email" value="<script>alert(1)</script>" />
</form>
<script>
    document.xssForm.submit();
</script>
```

The second option is a CSRF vulnerability, which may or may not exist on your site.

Assuming that this vulnerability only affects the attacker themselves, I think it's ok to say that there is minimal (if any) risk to this implementation, but that all output should be escaped as a standard. No need to overstate the risk of a particular vulnerability.